# Converting a string file path to vscode.Uri

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a means to convert an object of type `string` to `vscode.Uri`? In my case I have a string as a result of `vscode.workspace.rootPath` that I'd like to join to a am the string that is a partial path of that `rootPath`. In a custom type I'm using, I'm extending `vscode.TreeItem` that has a `Uri` property of type `vscode.Uri` path.

For reasons unknown to me `vscode.uri("c:\\some\\path")` is not being liked by the compiler.

Is this a type that can even be converted to or from?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the static [`Uri.file(path)`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Uri.file) function to create a `vscode.Uri` from a string file path:

```ts
let uri = vscode.Uri.file("c:\\some\\path");
```

To obtain the path in string form again, use [`fsPath`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Uri.fsPath):

```ts
let path = uri.fsPath; // c:\some\path
```

Something to be aware of is that the drive letter in Windows paths is normalized. So when doing a round-trip like this, it will be `c:` even if you originally started with `C:`. It will also replace `/` and `\` depending on the current platform.